# Access child in self method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

so I have this bit of code

```
class Brand < Applicationrecord
    has_many :products, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :brand

    def self.concatenate
        concat = ''
        self.products.each do |p|
           concat += p.name
        end
    end
end
```

Here in my class method, product is said to be undefined.
Can I access my children in a self method and if yes how am I supposed to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can I access my children in a self method

Depends.

> and if yes how am I supposed to do it ?

By obtaining an instance of `Brand` somehow. Certainly not by using `self`.

From what you have given us, I don't see why `concatenate` is a class method. Should be an instance method.

```
  def concatenate
    products.map(&:name).join
  end
```

Comment: I see my mistake. You're right it should be an instance method. Thanks